# Facebook payments - how to get application token and give it to graph api

Tags: php, facebook, payment

I'm trying to implement Facebook payments (on canvas), what I've got so far, is that FB is calling my callback URL, I can get the payment's ID, and now I'm supposed to call Graph Api to get the details. And this is what I can't do.

Here ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/payment ) is an example of doing it in PHP:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{payment-id}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

It returns NULL. They say later that:

> An app access token for the app that created the payment is required.

I have no idea how to get one and then how to send it along with the above request.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the following get request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials
```